# I want the arrow icon to flip up and down every time the state changes.and I want to animate it

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am using react, styled-components.
When state(visible) is set to true, DropMenu box1 and box2 will be displayed.
We want the ArrowDown icon to flip upward when state is true, and downward when false.
I also want to apply an animation when flipping it.
I want to add an animation like the Dropdown in the following site.

[Reference site](https://tailwindcomponents.com/component/responsive-sidebar-with-dropdown)

[code](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-dream-wybvu?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1561)

```
import "./styles.css";
import styled from "styled-components";
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { ArrowDown } from "./ArrowDown";

const Item = styled.div<{ active?: boolean }>`
  height: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 0px 30px;

  &:hover {
    background: #fafbfb;
  }
`;

const DropMenu = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: #899098;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  gap: 12px;
  :hover {
    color: gray;
  }
  div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 12px;
  }
`;

const DropText = styled.div`
  padding-left: 32px;
`;

export const App = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const handleDropVisibleChange = useCallback(() => {
    setVisible((prevVisible) => !prevVisible);
  }, [visible]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Item onClick={handleDropVisibleChange}>
        <DropMenu>
          <div>
            <span>Menu</span>
          </div>
          <ArrowDown />
        </DropMenu>
      </Item>
      {visible && (
        <div style={{ transition: "all 0.5s ease" }}>
          <Item>
            <DropMenu>
              <DropText>box1</DropText>
            </DropMenu>
          </Item>
          <Item>
            <DropMenu>
              <DropText>box2</DropText>
            </DropMenu>
          </Item>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TLDR

1. Change your MenuItem component warpper to something like

```
const DropMenuWrapper = styled.div<{ visible: boolean }>`
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  opacity: ${(props) => (props.visible ? 1 : 0)};
`;
```

2. replace the visibility switch mechanism with following

```
- {visible && (
-     <div style={{ transition: "all 0.5s ease" }}>

+     <DropMenuWrapper visible={visible}>
```

similar action can be added to the arrow-down icon also with style
(The ArrowDown SVG icon must accept style if it is custom written component)

```
<ArrowDown
  style={{
    transition: "all 0.5s ease",
    transform: `rotate(${visible ? 0 : "0.5turn"})`
  }}
/>
```

### Why this happened:

When a component (sub-component/element) is mounted in react, it starts a complete life cycle toward [browser paint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Painting_API).
So it is must have the property which causes the element to animate, for example, I added the opacity transition to the example itself, forcing it to animate in the first look and in disappearing.

Although it comes with some performance cost of having unseen elements still in the dom (but not visible), making it bad for accessibility too, it is the simplest way to achieve this behavior.

> **Consider this example** If you have an animated element, does it show the animation if you refresh the browser if the answer is yes, it will show animation in react too.

### Another way of doing some animation in react.

- Using third-party library [react-transtion-group](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/) which is heavily used in lots of packages e.g. [Material-UI](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui).

> In this case you can also trigger the end event and start to unmount the component as the animation disappears and end completely.

- Using [framer motion](https://www.framer.com/motion/)

If you want to take your understanding of what is needed for the transition when the component is unmounted and removed from aka dom, I highly encourage you to read the animation section of [svelte docuementation](https://svelte.dev/)

Comment: Type '{ style: { transition: string; transform: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  Property 'style' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322

Comment: The above error occurs and the animation is not applied

Comment: I enclosed it in a span tag and it worked.

Comment: const Rotate = styled.span<{ visible: boolean }>`
  transition: "all 0.5s ease";
  transform: ${({ visible }) => (visible ? "rotate(0)" : "rotate(0.5turn)")};
`;

Comment: Animations are not applied properly when using styled-components

Comment: When there is an element underneath the Wrapper, there will be a blank space underneath the Wrapper, and when false, I want to remove the blank space.

Comment: for the first issue, I guess you might add style to your component and pass that to the dom element underneath which I guess was svg. I mentioned that in the answer

Comment: for blank space, it is normal cause you only hide the element by the space is still occupied, if you want to remove the element space, you must either use third-party packages to trigger end animation event and then remove it, or consider changing the animation type for the actual hight of the element, or changing the positioning layout and achieving the same behavior with layer transition in css

Answer (score 0):

What I did, what might look stupid to more advanced developers was implement a simple check that would switch icons.

**Note: This doesn't have an animation, though. It's just a simple switcharoo**

1. define state in component
    `const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);`
2. Check whether icon is open or closed, if open, ExpandLessIcon, if closed ExpandMoreIcon.

```
        <ExpandLessIcon
          onClick={() => {
            setIsOpen(!isOpen);
          }}
        />
      ) : (
        <ExpandMoreIcon
          onClick={() => {
            setIsOpen(!isOpen);
          }}
        />
      )}
```

3. The way it works is, once clicked, it'll just flip the true false state over and over, which in turn will change icons.